# Чтение строки и символа в си

Tags: c

Всем привет. Необходимо прочитать строку и символ на языке си. Делаю это так:

```
fscanf(mf, "%s%c", str, symb);
```

Где mf - открытый файл. Но проблема в том, что символ не читается, читается только строчка. Вот файл, из которого производится чтение:

```
test s
```

test - строка, s - символ. Подскажите, как правильно их прочитать?

Answer (score 2):

Начнем с того, что `%s` - читать **одно слово**.
Затем - `%c`, читать символ. Какой символ после слова `test`? Именно - пробел.

Далее, **куда читать**? Нужно указать **адрес**.

Так что для чтения вашего `test s` нужно просто написать

```
fscanf(mf, "%s %c", str, &symb);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете это сделать, как показано в следующей демонстрационной программе

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    char s[10];
    char c;

    fscanf( stdin, "%9[^ ^\t] %c", s, &c );

    printf( "%s %c\n", s , c );

    return 0;
}
```